# User Control calling a method from the parent form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

Hi am creating a user control that will determine if a specific button on the main (parent) form will be enabled or disabled.

Ideally, when the conditions on the UC are met, i would just call a method from the parent form that would set the status. But that doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Main Form (form_load):

```
        Dim myTSButton As New ToolStripButton
        With myTSButton 
            .Text = ""
            .Image = Icons.My.Resources.myIcon.ToBitmap
            .Enabled = False
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf myTSButton_Click
            .Name = "myTSButton"
            tStrip.Items.Add(myTSButton)
        End With
```

The UC will show some checkboxes whose selection might enable or disable this myTSButton.

```
If ConditionsAreMet Then
  'Enable the myTSButton on my parent form!
End If
```

Comment: Form1.button.enabled = True ?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention... the button actually is a toolstripbutton dynamically created on the "Form1", so I can't access it like that.

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: An easy solution would be to add an eventhandler in the usercontrol that you call every time the Status changes.

Then the main form can add its own handler to the event, that updates the button

Comment: I think that's the way to go. I declared an event in the UC, raised it when conditionsAreMet and created a Method on the main form called "Protected Sub enableButton() Handles myUC1.enableButton" - this returns some errors: Event declared with an "As" clause must have a delegate type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If ConditionsAreMet Then
    Dim btn As ToolStripItem = CType(tStrip.Items.Find("myTSButton", True).ElementAt(0), ToolStripItem)
    btn.Enabled = True
End If
```

Tested with VB2010 with no errors.